# How do I get python to choose a random item from whatever the person wrote?

Tags: python

How do I get python to choose a random item from whatever the person wrote?, what I mean lets say the person wrote (Apple, Banana, Orange)
and then python would choose a random one from these 3 fruits?

How do I get it to do that? (the person who is using the app would write the items, I meant python would ask for example name the fruits and the person would write the fruits (not the programmer) and python would choose a random one. I'm thinking of using len but not sure how)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have ingested your user input into a list, you can use the random module:

```
import random

user_inputs = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]

random_fruit = random.choice(user_inputs)
```

If you need more than one random choice, you can use sample:

```
 random_fruit_sample = random.sample(user_inputs, 2)
```

Comment: wait i meant python would ask for example name the fruits and the person would write the fruits (not the programmer) and python would choose a random one. im thinking of using len but not sure how